# What will happen if I try to use GPU delegate under android 8.1

Tags: android, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-lite, nnapi

Here below is the system architecture for NNAPI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAzIF.png)

The NNAPI is available on Android 8.1 (API level27) or higher. 
What will happen if I try to use GPU delegate under android 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow's GPU delegate is not using NNAPI (see the [TFLite documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/delegates)).

A couple of corrections on Shree's answer.

- NNAPI will be delegating to GPU or any other available device even in Android 8.1 depending on the availability of NNAPI implementations.
- The **ANeuralNetworksCompilation_createForDevices()**  API is used when you want to address a specific set of devices, if you use **ANeuralNetworksCompilation_create()** the device selection will be done by NNAPI.
- The choice between the two different API (**createForDevices** or **create**) is controlled by the acceleratorName option in the delegate creation.

Comment: I can't really find any doc reference explaining the use of .acceleratorName , what I understood from what you said is that it is possible to set hardware runtime (gpu/dsp) for the NNAPI using this?

Answer (score 0):

NNAPI is available on all Android devices running Android 8.1 (API level 27) or higher

Only the **CPU fallback** was available on **Oreo MR1(8.1.0)**

Kindly refer to the following discussion about TFLite demo app performance with NNAPI on Pixel 2 device (Android 8.1) - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19317 - This claims that no improvement in the performance because there is no GPU and DSP NN drivers. So when NNAPI is called, **it will fall back to CPU**.

Since API level 29 (**Android 10**) only, **ANeuralNetworksCompilation_createForDevices()** is supported by NNAPI - This will create a ANeuralNetworksCompilation to compile the given model for a specified set of devices (**GPU and DSP**)